# Why the elements are not added in given order to the arraylist in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

In one of a test method I have a `List` named modifiedRanges, which contain several Lists inside it. I have written the following code to add elements (`List`s) to the root `List` (modifiedRanges) in order.

```
 List<List<String>> modifiedRanges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listRange1 = Arrays.asList("45,50/45,53");
        List<String> listRange2 = Arrays.asList("44,49/44,52");
        List<String> listRange3 = Arrays.asList("819,827/819,829", "901,912/903,916", "1078,1098/1082,1107",
                "1140,1156/1149,1155", "1162,1168/1161,1166", "1276,1281/1274,1287", "1331,1336/1337,1367");
        List<String> listRange4 = Arrays.asList("16,26/16,29", "57,60/60,71");

        modifiedRanges.add(listRange1);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange2);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange3);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange4);
```

But when I print the modifiedRanges `List` the order is not exactly as I added the elements ( ran as a test case in Intellij IDEA)

output:

> ```
> [[45,50/45,53], [44,49/44,52], [16,26/16,29, 57,60/60,71], [819,827/819,829, 901,912/903,916, 1078,1098/1082,1107, 1140,1156/1149,1155, 1162,1168/1161,1166, 1276,1281/1274,1287, 1331,1336/1337,1367]]
> ```

I have even added the elements by mentioning the relevant index but still the results are same

```
            modifiedRanges.add(0,listRange1);
            modifiedRanges.add(1,listRange2);
            modifiedRanges.add(2,listRange3);
            modifiedRanges.add(3,listRange4);
```

How to fix this so that I can get elements in correct order as below

> ```
> [[45,50/45,53], [44,49/44,52], [819,827/819,829, 901,912/903,916, 1078,1098/1082,1107, 1140,1156/1149,1155, 1162,1168/1161,1166, 1276,1281/1274,1287, 1331,1336/1337,1367], [16,26/16,29, 57,60/60,71]]
> ```

**Edit**
This is the full code snippet of the test case

```
@Test
    public void testGetFilesChangedAndModifyingLineRanges() throws CodeQualityMetricsException {
        SdkGitHubClient sdkGitHubClient = new SdkGitHubClient(githubToken);
        Map<String, List<String>> fileNamesAndPatches = sdkGitHubClient.getFilesChanged
                ("wso2/carbon-apimgt", "eaa45529cbabc5f30a2ffaa4781821ad0a5223ab");
        List<String> fileChanged = new ArrayList<>();
        fileChanged.add("features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature/src/main" +
                "/resources/publisher/site/themes/wso2/templates/sso/logout/template.jag");
        fileChanged.add("features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store" +
                ".feature/src/main/resources/store/site/themes/wso2" +
                "/templates/sso/logout/template.jag");
        fileChanged.add("components/sso-hostobject/org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects" +
                ".sso/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/hostobjects/" +
                "sso/internal/SessionInfo.java");
        fileChanged.add("components/sso-hostobject/org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects" +
                ".sso/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/hostobjects/" +
                "sso/SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject.java");

        List<String> fileNames = fileNamesAndPatches.get("fileNames");
        assertEquals("Files changed received from API response must be same as the Set of " +
                "filesChanged", fileChanged, fileNames);
        //testing  saveRelaventEditLineNumbers method
        List<List<String>> modifiedRanges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listRange1 = Arrays.asList("45,50/45,53");
        List<String> listRange2 = Arrays.asList("44,49/44,52");
        List<String> listRange3 = Arrays.asList("819,827/819,829", "901,912/903,916", "1078,1098/1082,1107",
                "1140,1156/1149,1155", "1162,1168/1161,1166", "1276,1281/1274,1287", "1331,1336/1337,1367");
        List<String> listRange4 = Arrays.asList("16,26/16,29", "57,60/60,71");
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange1);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange2);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange3);
        modifiedRanges.add(listRange4);

        List<String> patchString = fileNamesAndPatches.get("patchString");
        ChangesFinder changesFinder = new ChangesFinder();
        changesFinder.saveRelaventEditLineNumbers(fileNames, patchString);
        assertEquals("Modified line ranges received from the method must be equal to the hardcoded " +
                "modifiedRanges list", modifiedRanges, changesFinder.changedLineRanges);

    }
```

Comment: If you add only 3 and 4,what happens? Also, why can't you `Arrays.asList` the whole thing instead of add individually?

Comment: @Kasun I have run your code. it preserves the order with no issues. just `System.out.println(modifiedRanges.toString());`

Comment: The code you've shared surely adds the lists in the expected order. Presumably your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: I am running this code snippet inside a test case in `Intellij Idea`. As you have suggested I separate the code to another class and ran via terminal, it preserve the order. But why there is a difference in order when it runs in Idea

Comment: is there some piece of code which you are not showing here, that could be the reason for the  unexpected modification.

Comment: @Sikorski I have added the full test case code, please have a look and be kind enough to let me know why this happens

Comment: Judging to the output, the list is being sorted during the operation. But I guess that you're looking. I've used `List` so many times that I can trust it to add the values in the order the way it is added more than my girlfriend. I guess you're looking to a different output. (perhaps the result of `changesFinder.changedLineRanges`)

Comment: Also, you need to re-check how to write unit tests.

Comment: You’ve shown one minimal example that wasn’t verifiable. And you’ve shown one example with more code, but apparently neither complete nor verifiable. Could you by any chance [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @KarelG is it because two `assertEquals` are in the same method? Sorry for it, I just learned that it is not a good practise